# Global variable in SAS EG

Tags: sas, sas-macro, enterprise-guide

I have written two different SAS EG programs under the same project. The first one is to estimate a parameter, say A, which will be used in the second program. At the moment, once first program finish running, I manually set the parameter

```
%let A = 0.1;
```

in the second program. I just wonder is there a way to declare A as a global variable once it is calculated in the first program and then my second program can use it without the manual input?

Thanks.

Comment: Is the value, A in a table, rather than macro variable? If so, you can create a macro variable from that table in a few ways - proc sql or a data step are two options.

Comment: Yes, it is a number estimated in the first program, say 0.1. Is there any chance you can give an example of creating a macro variable here? I am new to SAS macro. Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

I'll post a data step, and use CALL SYMPUTX so you can assign the variable a global scope as well.

```
data _null_; *does not generate a data set;
    set have;
    call symputx('A', variable_name, 'G');
run;
```

Documentation for call symputx is here:
http://support.sas.com/documentation/cdl/en/lrdict/64316/HTML/default/viewer.htm#a002295697.htm

Answer (score 0):

Global macro variables persist for an entire SAS session (unless you delete them).  This means that in one EG session, if you run your %LET statement in the first program, it will be created in the session's global macro symbol table.  It will then be available to be used in any other program that runs during that same SAS session.

A SAS session persists in EG until you close EG, or manually disconnect from the SAS server.

Answer (score 0):

As a separate option beyond the scope of EG, if you were to run 2 separate programs in non-interactive mode a good way of sharing variables (or parameters of any kind) is to store them in a file and read them in at the start of the next program.

Using call symputx to assign a global variable will then allow these to persist throughout your new program.